# How to make these two simultaneous transactions succeed at all times, without causing a uniqueness violation?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, innodb

Let's pretend that there's a `tags` table with a unique field called `name`.

I have a transaction in which I perform a select to see if a tag with a specific name exists, and if it wasn't I create it:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM TAGS WHERE NAME = "FOO";
-- IF A TAG NAMED "FOO" DIDN'T EXIST THEN
INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES("FOO");
COMMIT;
```

When two clients run this transaction in the default isolation level (repeatable read), this interleaving will lead one of them to fail with a uniqueness violation:

```
START TRANSACTION;
                                                START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM TAGS WHERE NAME = "FOO";
                                                SELECT * FROM TAGS WHERE NAME = "FOO";
-- IF A TAG NAMED "FOO" DIDN'T EXIST THEN
INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES("FOO");
                                                -- IF A TAG NAMED "FOO" DIDN'T EXIST THEN
                                               INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES("FOO");
COMMIT;
                                               COMMIT;
```

I thought if I set the isolation level to serializable, I can avoid this situation, but I noticed that the same interleaving will then lead to a deadlock.

How can I modify the transaction so that it never fails due to uniqueness constraint violation?

For the record, this is the Ruby on Rails (ActiveRecord) code that corresponds to this scenario:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_tag(name)
    transaction do
      # setting isolation level to serializable leads to a deadlock
      # Tag.connection.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE")
      gets
      tag = Tag.find_by_name(name)
      if tag.nil?
        gets
        Tag.create!(:name => name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: kind of offtopic, but better use select name from tags where name = 'foo'; this will be index-covered query, which is faster than accessing the table

Comment: Can you performs Insert ... select? That [use mutex table](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/25/insert-if-not-exists-queries-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a type of race condition that Rails does not have any built-in ways for avoiding it out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Rails guy, but you could solve the problem from a SQL perspective by using a single query and adding `IGNORE` to the insert, which will not fail if the tag already exists.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TAGS VALUES("FOO");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. I didn't know about `IGNORE`, but I think it cannot be used in my situation. Is there a way to fix this using isolation levels? Like even with truly fully serialized transactions? or with `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`?

Comment: Hoping some Rails guru can chime in as I'm guessing there's a more idiomatic solution out there.

Comment: @KEverest Why can't `IGNORE` be used in your situation? Anyway, using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` before you start the transaction should do the trick as well.

Comment: I also don't know where the confusion is coming from. Set the `UNIQUE` key on the column, use `INSERT IGNORE` and forget about managing the uniqueness yourself by checking whether the record exists beforehand. It's a simple solution that works properly with or without transactions.

Comment: @MichaelMior in Rails, the insert statement is generated by ActiveRecord. But the select statements can be provided by the user. While it is possible to execute arbitrary insert statements by accessing to the underlying connection to the database, that would bypass a lot of ActiveRecord goodness such as proper ORM, associations, validations, etc.

Comment: @MichaelMior: I tried using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` before I start the transaction, and it makes the second transaction deadlock when it reaches the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: It should block the second transaction until the insert completes. Are you saying the first transaction never finishes?

Comment: After the first transaction finishes, the second one terminates with this error message: `ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.

Comment: Hmm, that's very odd. Are you executing these transactions manually?

Comment: @MichaelMior: yes, I do it manually to reproduce the interleaving shown in my question.